# Cannot resolve column name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, resteasy

I'm using JPA with hibernate under my small resteasy project deployed on wildfly.
I've got my persistence.xml file under directory:

> resources/META-INF/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="PostgresDS" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgresDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

So I'm dropping and creating database each time on startup.
When typing annotation `@Column(name="SomeName")` I've got error that

> "Cannot resolve column "Name" "

and as fix I'm supposed to attach data-source.
Should I prepare some hibernate config file(attaching data-source didn't help), maybe disabling some validation ?

Comment: what is the fully qualified name of the class which you have `@Column(name="SomeName")`.Suppose you have to put that inside `<class></class>` in your `persistence.xml `

Comment: @makeLifeEasier, when we specify the column name like  `@Column(name="SomeName")` SomeName is your table column name and SomeName must be same as table column name in your database.

Comment: @parladneupane So it's impossible to specify column name different than class field name before table creation on database.

Comment: However should I create hibernate config file to be consistent with standard ?

Comment: please post the class file. you can specify any name in the `@column` think you issue is with the `persistence.xml` configuration

Comment: **So it's impossible to specify column name different than class field** , it's possible , when you annotating  `@column(name = "name")` in class field , it tried to find the  **name** in your table column name. Once you map with corresponding column name via @column , you can name any name you want with your class field

Comment: Here's an idea : you actually post your JPA entity and its mapping information, as well as what schema your JPA provider is trying to create (likely in its log).